# How important is the manufacturer's warranty on a 700-series Canon camera?

Tags: canon, camera-recommendation

Looking for a good body to get started with. I'm offered a new 750D body or an almost new (7000 clicks) 760d body for the same price (545 EUR). Of course, the 760D has some minor pros. I think the best pro is the second small screen on top of the body that the 750D lacks. But the new 750D comes with a 5-year warranty. The used 760D comes with a 6-month warranty.

I was wondering if it would be wise decision to go for better specs or for a longer warranty. That's a personal question of course but do a lot of people need to use their warranty? How is the build quality of these models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important point for buying the new 750D would be the warranty, especially if the EU usually only requires 2 years of warranty for consumer electronics. 5 years warranty do add a little to the resale value when you decide to go for an upgrade.

Other than that I'd recommend to go to a store and try out both if you can and decide for yourself if you need the extra features of the 760D.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same thing. Not sure if I need the extra features. I was thinking the second extra screen is the best addition, but not sure at all if that is useful. The stores I visited did not really let me play with the cameras..

Comment: @Tieme The extra control wheel is the biggest differentiator for most users. It allows more (and faster) control of the camera without removing your eye from the viewfinder. It depends on what you're shooting how much that matters to you, though. For a fuller rundown of the differences between the 750D and 760D, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/83090/15871)

Answer (score 2):

There are situations where a warranty would be no concern at all. If any of your intended usage for the camera places it in conditions or subjects it to things that void the warranty then length of warranty is a non-issue.

Some possible scenarios not covered under warranty:

- Use in a wet environment that allows water to get inside the camera.
- Impact damage or damage caused by being subjected to excessive vibration.
- Having the camera customized by a third party, such as removing the IR filter from the sensor stack to convert the camera to an IR camera or having an aftermarket focusing screen installed.
- Storing the camera in an environment that allows fungus or mold to grow inside the lens or camera body.
- Taking the camera to [Burning Man](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2016/09/this-is-your-well-our-camera-at-burning-man/) or a [Color Run](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-ruin-your-gear-in-5-minutes-without-water/) or any other similar abuse.

As far as the build quality goes on the EOS Rebel/xx0D line, I haven't bought one since I purchased a Rebel XTi/400D in 2008. After 40,000+ shutter actuations  (mostly in the first three or four years I owned it) it still works fine in 2017, although it is rarely used these days.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for sketching out these scenarios!